# Insert filename into column

Tags: sql, ssis

I have a set of files that are dynamically changing, I am using the foreach loop container to update them. I am using two variables (1) for file path and (2) for source folder. I need to insert the file names into a separate column.

File names:

```
D:\SAFI\test1\XYZ0000_2016_04_Application_Report.csv`
D:\SAFI\test1\ABC0000.10_2016_04_Application_Report.csv`
```

I need to insert only XYZ0000 into a new column. How do I do it with the help of variables? I am using the derived column and need the output in a new column:

```
Filename
  XYZ0000
  ABC0000.10
```

Comment: Do you have 'D:\SAFI\test1\' common folder for all the files ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we consider that the non-interesting part of the file begins with the first occurrence of '_', you can use this expression:

```
SUBSTRING(@[User::Variable1FilePath],15,FINDSTRING( @[User::Variable1FilePath],"_" ,1 )-15)
```

supposing also that you have 'D:\SAFI\test1\' common folder for all the files (lenght 15 used in SUBSTRING function)

or you can consider the third '\' occurrence representing the end of the path
and try:

```
SUBSTRING(@[User::Variable1FilePath],FINDSTRING( @[User::Variable1FilePath],"\\" ,3 )+1,FINDSTRING( @[User::Variable1FilePath],"_" ,1 )-(FINDSTRING( @[User::Variable1FilePath],"\\" ,3 )+1))
```

I hope this help you.

Comment: @ Alex: can you please tell me what is this ** Variable4**

Comment: Sorry, it was a typo, it is always Variable1FilePath, I corrected the answer!

Comment: @ Alex: when i am assigning the variable with the file path, it is throwing an error

Comment: @ Alex this is the error i am receiving if i am giving the path in the variable.

Comment: the error is: Evaluating SUBSTRING failed with error code 0xC004708B.

Comment: Which is the content of content of your User::Variable1FilePath ?

Comment: it is the file path **D:\SAFI\test1\**

Comment: @ Alex: i got the desired result when pointing the location to one particular file, but how do I do it for dynamically changing files?

Comment: File name structure is always the same?

Comment: It may increase or decrease in size. or their may be  decimal values as well

Comment: Filename
  XYZ0000
  ABC0000.10

Comment: Filename
  XYZ0000
  ABC0000.10

Comment: try this:      `SUBSTRING(RIGHT(@[User::Variable1FilePath], FINDSTRING(REVERSE(@[User::Variable1FilePath]), "\\",1)-1),1,(FINDSTRING(RIGHT(@[User::Variable1FilePath], FINDSTRING(REVERSE(@[User::Variable1FilePath]), "\\",1)-1),"_" ,1 )-1))`

Answer (score 2):

Try below:

@FilePath:

```
D:\SAFI\test1\ABC0000.10_2016_04_Application_Report.csv
```

@FileName:

```
RIGHT( @[User::FilePath], FINDSTRING(REVERSE( @[User::FilePath]  ) , "\\", 1) - 1)

Result: ABC0000.10_2016_04_Application_Report.csv
```

@OnlyFile:

```
LEFT( @[User::FileName], FINDSTRING( @[User::FileName],"_",1 ) -1)

Result: ABC0000.10
```

Replace the @FileName with the expression of @Onlyfile to make it single variable.